# Batch Scripting - Listing files with a specific amount of characters in file name

Tags: windows, command-line, script, batch

I'm creating a batch script for a class and I've hit a roadblock.

I have to list all text files whose names are up to seven characters long on the entire `C:` drive - make the listing output in a wide formant - then append to Batch script file `output.txt`.

So far I have -->

```
dir c:\*txt/w/o/s/p >>c:/"My Batch Script File Assigment"/"Output"/"Batch Script File Output Data".txt
```

The above does everything except limit the search to files with only 1-7 characters in their name.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list files that are between 1-7 chars long you use the "?" (question mark). The question mark represents only one unknown character. Examples:

List all the file names starting with D and comprising five or less chars, and any ext:

```
C>DIR C:D????.*
```

To copy all files beginning with S and an ext of two chars or less:

```
C>COPY S*.?? A:
```

Delete all files that have a single char filename with a doc ext from the root:

```
C:\>del ?.doc
```

Limit a search to the 1-7 character file name...

```
C:\> DIR ???????.txt

dir c:???????.txt/w/o/s/p >c:/"My Batch Script File Assigment"/"Output"/"Batch Script File Output Data".txt
```

Comment: Wow that's brilliant! Thanks for that, I was tearing my hair out over that question.